# Why do C++ Maps of Objects differ on Mavericks and Mountain Lion

Tags: c++, macos, lldb

I have a problem that boils down to the following:

I have a C++ structure containing among other things a vector

```
struct Structure{                                                                                   
std::vector<int> c;
Structure();
Structure(std::vector<int> c_init);                                                                  
};

Structure::Structure( std::vector<int> c_init)                                                       
{c= c_init;
}                                                                                                    
Structure::Structure(){                                                                              
}
```

and the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "structr.h"


using namespace std;


int main () {

map<int, Structure*> StructureMap;
vector<int> foo;
foo.push_back(39);
foo.push_back(70);
foo.push_back(72);
StructureMap[1]=new Structure( foo);  

cout << (*StructureMap[1]).c[0] << "\n" ; 

return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with g++ the output is both on Mavericks and Mountain Lion "39", as I assume it should be. 
However, if I step through the program with lldb on Mavericks I receive

```
   20   StructureMap[1]=new Structure( foo); 
   21   
-> 22   cout << (*StructureMap[1]).c[0] << "\n" ;
   23   
   24   return 0;
   25   }
(lldb) p *StructureMap[1]
(Structure) $6 = {
  c = size=3 {
    [0] = 39
    [1] = 70
    [2] = 72
  }
}
```

while on Mountain Lion I get

```
   19   foo.push_back(72); 
   20   StructureMap[1]=new Structure( foo); 
   21   
-> 22   cout << (*StructureMap[1]).c[0] << "\n" ;
   23   
   24   return 0;
   25   }
(lldb) p *StructureMap[1]
error: call to a function 'std::map<int,Structure*,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Structure*> > >::operator[](int const&)' that is not present in the target
error: Couldn't materialize struct: Structure hasn't been laid out yet
(lldb)
```

Why is the Map not properly filled in Mountain Lion and even more confusing to me, why is the output still "39", even though the map is empty ?

Thanks a million - Rob

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Couldn't materialize struct: Couldn't read eax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704310/error-couldnt-materialize-struct-couldnt-read-eax)

Answer (score 0):

The map is properly filled, as the result `39` shows. Mountain Lion's `lldb` doesn't understand the `Structure` type, from your error message. That is unrelated to the map itself.

This isn't too surprising. Writing good debuggers is hard, and as Wikipedia states "LLDB is in early development"

Comment: Actually this is most likely a debug info problem - unless you are manually compiling the same gcc, you are most definitely using clang, and different versions thereof

One interesting thing you could do is compare the DWARF emitted on Lion vs. the one emitted on Mountain Lion and see where the differences lie.

As an aside, you might be able to use data formatters to access your std::map anyway, for instance by doing p *StructureMap without indexing