# Crash when trying to access Contacts Framework in iOS 10

Tags: ios, contacts, ios10

I am trying to access the Contacts framework so I can save a new contact into the users Addressbook. I have the following code ...

```
import Contacts
import ContactsUI
```

at the head of the file and include a method ...

```
func requestForAccess(completion: (granted: Bool) -> ()) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.rawValue), 0), {
        let authStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts)

        switch authStatus {
        case .Authorized:
            completion(granted: true)
        case .Denied, .NotDetermined:

            // CRASH HERE before the completion block is called, after calling 
            // requestAccessForEntityType

            self.contactStore.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts, completionHandler: { (access, accessError) -> () in
                if access {
                    completion(granted: access)
                } else {
                    if authStatus == .Denied {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> () in
                            let msg = "\(accessError!.localizedDescription)\n\nPlease allow the app to access your contacts through the Settings."
                            //self.alertService.showAlert(msg)
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        default:
            completion(granted: false)
        }
    })
}
```

At the line marked, there is a `SIABRT` crash. Winding down the stack and running `po $arg1` throws up the following ...

```
error: Couldn't materialize: couldn't read the value of register x0
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
```

I have the necessary line in `Info.plist` in the root `dict`

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need to access Contacts to import entries direct from the app.</string>
```

I have also included `Contacts.framework` and `ContactsUI.framework` in 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' in the target properties (General)

Comment: Is your device running iOS 10? Cleaning the project, deleting the app from the device or restarting sometimes helps

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704310/error-couldnt-materialize-struct-couldnt-read-eax

Comment: @josip I tried uninstalling from phone, restarting phone, restarting XCode and cleaning the project but no luck :(

Comment: @Amit, I tried `register read` on each of the threads but nothing that I could understand as debug messages appeared

Comment: Is CNContactStore framework added as required of as optional in build phases? Why are you trying to access request in background thread?

Comment: Unrelated but please note that there is no reason to call `requestAccessForEntityType` when the current authorization is "denied". The user will not be prompted again. The call to `requestAccessForEntityType` will simply return "denied" again without asking the user. You should instead show an alert telling the user access is currently denied and offer a chance to launch the app's Settings page where the user can enable the access.

Comment: @Josip, there is no `CNContactStore.framework` as far as I can see but I did include `Contacts.framework` and `ContactsUI.framework`. I access in the background since it is a long running process and one article I read suggested accessing in a background thread - it makes no difference to the crash though if I run background or on the main thread...

Comment: Sorry I was thinking on Contacts.framework. Is this happening on a device or Simulator?

Comment: @Josip its on my personal iPhone SE so is signed-in with contacts etc. I get the same crash on the simulator. I have a feeling that it might be something to do with the calling context, this code is called on a service class, not on the AppDelegate nor a ViewController ...

Comment: It should work independent from which class it is called. Can you create test project which will have only this peace of code for requesting access and see if it happens there? If it doesn't happen there then you know that problem is only in your project.

Comment: @Josip B, I have tried a sample project and it works fine. I can't see what the problem is with my actual project though. I have edited my projects to call the code in exactly the same way (i.e. from a ViewController) set the same Swift Version (legacy), iOS target (9.3), imported the same contact libraries, and included the same info.plist lines ... I'm really at a loss

Answer (score 4):

I have added plist entry for contact description and modified your code a little bit to use in my swift 3.0 project, following code is working like a charm on my iOS 10.0.2

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated);
        self.requestForAccess { (gotAccess) in
            print(gotAccess)
        }
    }

    func requestForAccess(_ completion: @escaping (_ granted: Bool) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async { 
            let authStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)

            switch authStatus {
            case .authorized:
                completion(true)
            case .denied, .notDetermined:

                self.contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { (access, accessError) -> () in
                    if access {
                        completion(access)
                    } else {
                        if authStatus == .denied {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let msg = "\(accessError!.localizedDescription)\n\nPlease allow the app to access your contacts through the Settings."
                                print(msg)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            default:
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I figured it out - it wasn't anything obvious I'm afraid.

For some reason XCode had replicated my `Info.plist` and was parsing and loading a copy rather than the `Info.plist` in my root directory. Although I added the `NSContactsUsageDescription` to one file, it was reading the other, hence the crash.